# XPath : Get nodes where child node contains an attributeHow to select node that have and attribute and whose parent have another attribute in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

i have an XML like

```
<Validation>
    <Presentation>
        <Slide Tag = "Pippo">
            <Shape Name = "Pluto"/>
        </Slide>
        <Shape Name = "Pluto"/>
    </Presentation>
</Validation>
```

how can i improve this c# code snippet

```
 String xPath = string.Format("/Validation/Presentation/Shape[@Name='{0}'][1]", "Pluto");
 XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xPath);
```

to get only the shape node with attribute Name "Pluto" whose parent have the attribute Tag "Pippo"?

Answer (score 4):

You can get this node using following Xpath string:

```
string xPath = string.Format("//*[@Tag='{0}']/Shape[@Name='{1}']", "Pippo","Pluto");
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xPath);
```

Comment: Is it equivalent to xPath = string.Format("/Validation/Presentation/Slide[@Tag='{0}']/Shape[@Name='{1}'][1]", "Pippo", "Pluto"); ?

Comment: @Matt3o it is not. Your query selects `Shape` having  name Pluto and parent `/Validation/Presentation/Slide` with tag Pippo. My query selects exactly as it was stated in your question: "Shape node with attribute Name "Pluto" whose parent have the attribute Tag "Pippo" - i.e. parent can be any node having this tag, not only `/Validation/Presentation/Slide`.